# interview assesment. Trouble understanding challenge

Tags: python

I am a little confused as to how to implement code an exercise. This is the description I was given:

Write an app in python that takes as input a list of files and a provider parameter. Depending on the provider parameter either write the files to a database, the file system, or print the files to console or popup window. The parameter values are “provider1” for database, “provider2” for file system, “provider3” for console/popup.

```
provider3 = []

user_input = input("Which provider would you like to choose? ")
for i in user_input:
    if i  == 'provider3':
               provider3 = i  ++1
               provider3 = provider3.append(i)
               provider3 = 'console pop up'
               print (provider3[i])`
```

Comment: Write 3 functions, one for each of the options.  Then your main application just needs to call the correct function based on the input.

Comment: man I'm slumped. I've tried a few things but I'm not getting the problem being asked. I'm sure i know or have done this before but it seems I'm not catching on. I have till noon tomorrow to finish this and its not looking good for me right about now. any help or sample code to go off of will help :(